# Java Web Service

Tags: java, веб-программирование, netbeans

Создал web приложение в netbeans создал в нем web сервис на сервере glassfish (использует java 1.8).
В этом web сервисе создал метод add

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "add")
public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    return i + j;
}
```

При тестировании сервиса открывается страница в браузере, ввожу два числа, жму на кнопку add
Ответ:

> WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message : null;
>   Refer to the server log for more details
>
> ```
> Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat
> ```
>
> org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:318)at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:82)at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:133)at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:293)...
>   32 more Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException:
>   Client received SOAP Fault from server:
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error
>   creating managed object for class: class
>   org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS Please see the server log to find more
>   detail regarding exact cause of the failure.at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:163)at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:98)at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:223)at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:176)at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:263)at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:62)at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:131)at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy320.add(Unknown Source)... 37 more

Не знаю то что выше это логи сервера или нет, если нужно что-то еще напишите скину. В создании web приложений вообще не шарю, делаю лабу.

GalculatorWS^

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.me.calculator;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

/**
 *
 * @author nail1
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorWS")
public class CalculatorWS {


    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "add")
    public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на это: `Error creating managed object for class: class org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS Please see the server log to find more detail`. Ошибка в классе org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS. Ищите там. То, что вы привели, это не серверный лог. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395094/i-get-error-creating-managed-object-for-class-class-org-jboss-weld-servlet-wel) вопрос с аналогичной ошибкой, там есть ответ, возможно он подойдёт и вам.

Comment: Добавил код этого класса. Не знаю в чем там ошибка.